# How to add and verify tokens (against CSRF etc.) in links not forms in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know how to enable CSRF in forms in CodeIgniter, however I am not sure how to implement this feature in CodeIgniter classic link (e.g. for adding/deleting private messages, posts etc. in admin area)

Now I am using something like this:

**VIEW**

```
<?php echo anchor('account/delete_private_message/'.$obj->pmID, 'delete mesage', array('onclick' => 'return confirm(\'Do you really want to delete this private message?\');', 'class' => 'delete-message-button')); ?>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function delete_private_message($pmID = '')
    {

        $deleted_pm = $this->account_model->delete_pm($pmID);

        if($deleted_pm)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status', 'PM was deleted successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status', 'Error');
        }
        redirect('account/private_messages');
    }
```

**MODEL**

```
function delete_pm($pmID)
    {

        $return = 0;
        if(!empty($pmID))
        {
            $this->db->where('pmID', $pmID);
            $result = $this->db->delete('private_messages');
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

And if user click on OK in the popup the message is deleted.

The question is how to add token to the link and to the session of the user and verify it etc. I do not know how to achieve this to work properly.

**EDIT:** I just guess I have to add the generated token at the end of the link like:

> account/delete_private_message/1239/dfdf6e7re67a6e87r6e87r69876bn3

and the value dfdf6e7re67a6e87r6e87r69876bn3 also in the session of the current user and verify them in controller. However, what ecxactly should I do, I don't know. So, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct - just pass the CSRF token as part of the link. The example below should help (but I havent tested it)

```
function delete_private_message($pmID = '', $token = null)
{
    // Check supplied token is valid
    if ( ! ($this->_check_token($token)))
    {
        // Not valid
        $this->session->set_flashdata('status', 'Error');
        redirect('account/private_messages');
    }


    if($this->account_model->delete_pm($pmID))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('status', 'PM was deleted successfully');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('status', 'Error');
    }
    redirect('account/private_messages');
}


function _check_token ($token)
{
      return ($token === $_COOKIE[$this->csrf_cookie_name]);
}
```

**p.s.** you have an error in your model code

```
$return = 0;
```

should be

```
$result = 0;
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know

Comment: Hmm, could you halp me with the code a little bit ;). I am not using csrf globally and I need to set cookies and tokens in the view and get cookies and tokens manually. I am using <?php $csrf_hash = $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?> to set token to the link and it works. But I have problem to save this value inside my cookie in a cookie with the name: csrf_cookie_name. But set_cookie is not working for me in the view ;(. Could you help me what to add in my view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using a lot of ajax forms (no delete stuff) on my page and it makes problems. Is it possible to set cookie after <?php $csrf_hash = $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?> and if yes how? E.g. this code is not working: $csrf_cookie_value = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
  $this->input->set_cookie('csrf_cookie_name', $csrf_cookie_value);
  echo $this->input->cookie('csrf_cookie_name'); Nothing is echoed out.

Comment: you could approach this completely differently - when the user logs in - generate a random string and store it in the session. then use this string to do the comparision. It is the 'same thing' as a CSRF token - but you are making your own instead of using the CI one